# How To Covert Output From "array_walk" Back To An Array

Tags: php

I am taking strings from an array and using the substr() function to extract specific characters from those strings. These string characters are represented as time duration based on the time it took for a contractor to complete a certain task. The format looks like this:

```
$duration = array(
    '00:44:32', 
    '02:06:15',
    '03:14:36',
    '00:45:16'
);
```

And this is the function I am using to convert those extracted characters, in order to convert the durations into decimal form:

```
$myarray = $duration;
function func($myarray) {
    $hours = substr($myarray, -8, 2);
    $minutes = substr($myarray, -5, 2);
    $seconds = substr($myarray, -2);
    $hms_converted = ($hours + ($minutes/60) + ($seconds/3600));
    $decimal = round($hms_converted, 4);
    echo $decimal . ",";
}
array_walk($myarray, 'func');
```

At this point the array_walk function is doing it's job and spitting out the results for each record in the array. Which looks like this:

```
<b>0.7422,2.1042,3.2433,0.7544</b>
```

I have tried exploding array_walk like so. But this does not work.

```
explode(",", array_walk($myarray, 'func'));

returns 0.7422,2.1042,3.2433,0.7544
```

I have also tried assigning array_walk to a variable like so. But to no avail, I am not able to convert back to an array.

```
$var = array_walk($myarray, 'func');
explode(",", $var);

returns 0.7422,2.1042,3.2433,0.7544
```

Here is the complete code as one chunk

```
$duration = array(
    '00:44:32', 
    '02:06:15',
    '03:14:36',
    '00:45:16'
);

$myarray = $duration;
function func($myarray) {
    $hours = substr($myarray, -8, 2);
    $minutes = substr($myarray, -5, 2);
    $seconds = substr($myarray, -2);
    $hms_converted = ($hours + ($minutes/60) + ($seconds/3600));
    $decimal = round($hms_converted, 4);
    echo $decimal . ",";
}
array_walk($myarray, 'func');
```

The idea is to replace:

```
$duration = array(
    '00:44:32', 
    '02:06:15',
    '03:14:36',
    '00:45:16'
);
```

With:

```
$duration = array(
    '0.7422', 
    '2.1042',
    '3.2433',
    '0.7544'
);
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `array_walk` with `array_map` and update your callback function to **`return`** value, not to `echo` it:

```
$myarray = $duration;
function func($myarray) {
    $hours = substr($myarray, -8, 2);
    $minutes = substr($myarray, -5, 2);
    $seconds = substr($myarray, -2);
    $hms_converted = ($hours + ($minutes/60) + ($seconds/3600));
    $decimal = round($hms_converted, 4);
    // RETURN the value
    return $decimal;
}
$newArray = array_map('func', $myarray);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested @u_mulder. But the var_dump returned null on all elements.
var_dump($newArray); 

array (size=4)
  0 => null
  1 => null
  2 => null
  3 => null

Comment: Use this fiddle https://3v4l.org/T63n1 and compare with your code.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. I was using echo instead of return. This helps a lot. Thank you so much, man. I've spent 2 whole days this weekend trying to figure this out. Would love to buy you a coffee.

Answer (score 0):

A simple foreach is enough here and is clearer what is done:

```
$duration = array(
    '00:44:32', 
    '02:06:15',
    '03:14:36',
    '00:45:16'
);

foreach($duration as $key => $strTime){
  list($h,$m,$s) = explode(":",$strTime);
  $newDuration[$key] = round($h + $m/60 + $s/3600, 4);
}

echo "<pre>".var_export($newDuration, true)."</pre>";
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 0.7422,
  1 => 2.1042,
  2 => 3.2433,
  3 => 0.7544,
)
```

If you want to overwrite the array $duration, use $duration instead of $newDuration.